# Stream Live audio TO raspberry pi

Tags: wireless, audio

I want to stream live audio stream from my ubuntu running laptop to my pi, both of which are connected to the same network. I have read about ffmpeg and installed it too but can not get the mic output to /dev/dsp. Also I do not understand how exactly rtp works. 
I already have a ssh connection running with the pi as the server.

Any help would be really appreciated, ThankYou.

Comment: You might to check this [post](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11735/using-pi-to-stream-all-audio-output-from-my-pc-to-my-stereo) as well as this [thread](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=11124)

Comment: @xfx Did you flag it as a duplicate?

Comment: I've used ShairPort on my DietPi and  http://tuneblade.com on my windows. 0ms latency!